# flat table of time periods

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create a sproc that spews out a dynamic flat table of user friendly time periods to be consumed somewhere else. This is my first attempt:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE aaLogi.GetQuickPeriods

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Today DATETIME;
    DECLARE @WeekStart DATETIME;

    SET @Today = GETDATE();
    SET @WeekStart = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19050101', @Today), '19050101'); 

        DECLARE @QuickPeriods TABLE
    (
      QuickPeriod NVARCHAR(max), 
      FromDateTime DATETIME,
      ToDateTime DATETIME
    )

    INSERT INTO @QuickPeriods (QuickPeriod, FromDateTime, ToDateTime)
    VALUES ('Today', @Today, @Today) 

    INSERT INTO @QuickPeriods (QuickPeriod, FromDateTime, ToDateTime)
    VALUES ('This Week', @WeekStart, DATEADD(day, 7, @WeekStart)) 

    INSERT INTO @QuickPeriods (QuickPeriod, FromDateTime, ToDateTime)
    VALUES ('Week to Date', @WeekStart, @Today)

    SELECT * FROM @QuickPeriods

END
GO
```

This is all very procedural. Is there a more set based/efficient way? Sorry my TSQL is not very fluent yet ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert statement can be a bit more simplified the rest looks fine to me, if it gives you the expected results

```
INSERT INTO @QuickPeriods (QuickPeriod, FromDateTime, ToDateTime)
SELECT 'Today'      , @Today    , @Today
UNION ALL
SELECT 'This Week'  , @WeekStart, DATEADD(day, 7, @WeekStart)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Week to Date', @WeekStart, @Today
```

> Also why QuickPeriod field is NVARCHAR(max) ???  Longest string value is 
>   `'Week to Date'` which I think is 12 characters, so why not just use
>   NVARCHAR(12) or (15).

Comment: was just wandering if creating temp table instead of table variable would increase performance.

Comment: In this case table variable works just fine. but if you are inserting a lot of data into a table and doing some complex operations on it, and having some indexes on that table can help the query performance only then I would use a temp table , create indexes on it to tune the queries this is something you can only do on Temp tables .On table variables you cannot define indexes. in this case for such a simple operation table varible is more suitable.